# How to set the display device to None in a python script?

Tags: python, scene, color-management

I want to set the display device in Blender 2.69 to 'None' rather than 'sRGB' using a python script.

I have tried the following:

`bpy.data.scenes[0].display_settings.display_device = 'None'`

and

`bpy.data.scenes[0].display_device = 'None'`

The first one gave this error:

> TypeError: bpy_struct: item.attr = val: enum "None" not found in ('sRGB')

and the second one gave this error:

> AttributeError: 'Scene' object has no attribute 'display_device'

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Works in 2.76b...

Comment: Unfortunately, switching the Blender version is currently not an option :(

Comment: Can't reproduce it - also works in 2.69 linux (http://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.69/)

Comment: @poor: It was some corruption in the installation files I think, so removing Blender then installing it again solved the issue... Thanks for your care! :)

Comment: You are welcome, but then we should close it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue is not reproducible.

Comment: what do u mean? how to close it?

Comment: oh, I see, should I delete the question?

Comment: I'd recommend leaving the question as it is, others will close it for you. Might be a good idea to start with the tour: http://blender.stackexchange.com/tour. Anyway, enjoy blender.se!