# How to turn off gamma correction with Python in Blender 2.69

Tags: python, color-management

I'm trying to render surface normals for my scene, and I've gotten it to work in Blender 2.78. One of the important steps was to eliminate the gamma correction which was whitening the image. I did this in 2.78 by doing

```
scene.view_settings.view_transform = 'Raw'
```

Unfortunately I also need this to work in Blender 2.69, but I can't find the appropriate setting as the 'Raw' enum was introduced after 2.69.

I've tried setting it to 'NONE' (which the Blender 2.69 API lists as an option) but this throws an error saying that the only option is 'Default'. I've also tried directly setting

```
scene.view_settings.gamma = 0.0
```

But this has no effect.

---

Update: Thanks for your answer, Troy. Ultimately I'm trying to create a png image with the surface normals that I'll use for another task. This other task needs me to remap the colors of the surface normals (to look like this: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.4958v1.pdf).

I'm definitely open to using another path to producing normals, but I need to use only Python scripting. `Non-color Data` sounds promising. Would I be able to render something using nodes, and then save that render (from an output node, not from the RenderLayer) as `Non-color Data`? Please let me know if I'm not being clear!

---

Update 2: Thanks, Sambler. When I set `scene.display_settings.display_device = 'XYX'` I get `TypeError: bpy_struct: item.attr = val: enum "XYZ" not found in ('sRGB')`.

Trying to change

```
scene.display_settings.display_device = 'sRGB'
scene.view_settings.view_transform = 'Raw'
```

yields `TypeError: bpy_struct: item.attr = val: enum "Raw" not found in ('Default')`

[This question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41687/how-to-set-the-display-device-to-none-in-a-python-script) seems pertinent. In this question the solution was to reinstall Blender. As I'm working on a shared cluster, to ask the admin to reinstall Blender in order to help me debug is, ideally, a last resort.

Comment: PNG is a less that sub optimal format. If you render to EXR and flag as ````Non-Color Data```` you should be absolutely fine. This can also be done via Python of course. Never use PNG, it is a truly worthless format.

Comment: Rather than asking to reinstall - consider asking to update to something less than 3 years old. On the remote blender what do you get for `bpy.app.ocio.supported`

Answer (score 4):

Wrong approach.

Simply render or load an image and tag it as `Non-color Data` in the UV Image editors properties panel. Being a good imager, you are already using the EXR format exclusively, as it is a linearized, high precision encoding format for both colour and data.

The `Non-color Data` tag keeps the buffer entirely out of the colour transform pipeline.

> I'm definitely open to using another path to producing normals, but I need to use only Python scripting. Non-color Data sounds promising. Would I be able to render something using nodes, and then save that render (from an output node, not from the RenderLayer) as Non-color Data? Please let me know if I'm not being clear!

The colour transform tag on an image buffer is only metadata, and as such, if you save that buffer as an EXR, there is nothing more that you need to do. Simply load the EXR, then use Python to set the buffer's tag to `Non-Color Data` and you are done. Those values will not be put through any view transform.

It should be noted that when viewing `Non-Color Data` in the viewport, it might *seem* that the view is identical to when it is set to `linear`. The difference is that `linear` is defined as a colour transform and will get passed through various transforms, where, as stated above, `Non-Color Data` *always* will pass through untransformed.

Comment: Hey that's a good tip, I didn't know this ;-)

Answer (score -1):

`scene.view_settings.view_transform` is part of the colour management settings, the values accepted vary based on the display device setting. I see the same values available in 2.68 and 2.78

When `scene.display_settings.display_device == 'None'` `view_transform` can only be set to 'Default'

When `display_device == 'Rec709'` `view_transform` can be set to 'Default' or 'RRT'

When `display_device == 'XYZ'` `view_transform` can be set to 'Default', 'RRT', 'DCI', 'Raw' or 'Log'

When `display_device == 'sRGB'` `view_transform` can be set to 'Default', 'RRT', 'Film', 'Raw' or 'Log'

Comment: That is the view transform. Views have nothing to do with internal representation of data, nor the issue of data based buffers such as the OP's question, which setting data to ````Non-Color Data```` keeps the buffer out of the transformation chain.

Comment: It is the setting being changed in 2.78 that produced the desired result but fails in 2.69. It may not be the best solution but it is what is failing.

Comment: Sorry, no. It is completely misunderstanding colour management. You do *not* disable a view. Views are for colour data. You tag data that isn't colour as such. It isn't terribly complex.

Comment: But he is trying to disable colour management so that a rendered image isn't adjusted by the colour management. I would expect only one render from the scene is desired this way so disabling colour management for one render could be easier than changing each image setting based on the render being done. But that's just an assumption.

Comment: "But he is trying to disable colour management so that a rendered image isn't adjusted by colour management." This is *precisely* what is addressed via EXR. ````Non-Color Data```` should also work on some display referred image formats.